# Can install4j install a server certificate

Tags: java, ssl, install4j

My Java application needs to connect to a secure web site. I'd like to avoid requiring users to import the certificate manually (e.g., using the certificate manager on Windows or the Key Chain tool on MacOS).

Can the installer import a server certificate on the machine to enable my Java application to accept requests over HTTPS or WSS?

Comment: As of install4j 6.1, this is not one of the features offered by install4j.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to import a certificate from the installer using scripts.